# アプリケーションのdllをDebug版に変更してデバッグしたいが、動かない

Tags: c++, c, mfc

### 環境と状況

ローカルPC Windows10 x64 VisualStudio2017
仮想環境   Windows10 x64

ローカルPCでアプリケーション作成し、そのインストーラにて仮想環境にてアプリをインストールした。
リモートデバッガを使って、仮想環境のアプリケーションのプログラムをローカルPCからデバッグしようとしている。

### やりたいこと

仮想環境にインストールしたアプリケーションのデバッグをローカルPCから行いたいが、
ReleaseモードでのデバッグしかできないのでDebugモードでデバッグを行いたい。
（Release版でのデバッグはできたのですが、最適化のせいでうまくデバッグできないため）

### 困っていること

仮想環境のプログラムのBinフォルダ内のdllはRelease版のDLLを使っているようなので、
デバッグを行いたいプロジェクトのdllをDebug版のdllに変更しても動かないのでデバッグできない。

### 調査したこと

https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/windows/preparing-a-test-machine-to-run-a-debug-executable?view=vs-2019
上記サイトを参考にすると、Debug版は～d.dllファイルを参照していると記載がある。
なので、仮想環境のBinフォルダ内のdllやexeをすべてDebug版に差し替えた。
そしてアプリケーションを起動してみると
「mfc140d.dllが見つからないため、コードの実行を継続できません。」というエラーがでる。
ということは、アプリケーションは、mfc140.dllを参照しようとするが、
差し替えたdllやexeがmfc140d.dllを参照しようとしているのではないか？
なのであれば、mfc140d.dllを参照しようとしている原因を突き止めればいいのでは？

ここまで考えたのですが、これ以上先に進みませんでした。

そもそも、Release版の中にDebug版のdllを混在させること自体が間違っているのか。
それすらわかりません。

Dependency WalkerでDebug版とRelease版の依存関係を調べると、
Debug版  ：mfc140d.dll
Release版：mfc140.dll
となっていたので、Debug版がmfc140d.dllを参照しようとしていることは確かと思います。

どなたか知見ございましたらご教授いただけませんでしょうか？

Comment: いまいち質問の意図が把握できていないのですが、今回はデバッグ版で実行させたいのですよね？だとしたらmfc140d.dllが仮想環境側にも必要だと思います。もう少しどうやって仮想環境のアプリケーションをデバッグしているか(リモートデバッグを使用している等)の情報が欲しいです。デバッグ版のdllはリリース版のdllと競合することはないはずですので、差し替える必要はなく、両方混在していても必要な方を読み込んでアプリケーションが起動すると思いますよ。

Comment: Sugiyama Koichiさん
ありがとうございます。リモートデバッガを使おうとしていることを追記しました。仮想環境にmfc140d.dllがないか確認してみます！確認次第またコメント編集します

Comment: Sugiyama Koichiさん
確認したところ、仮想環境にmfc140d.dllがありませんでした。そもそもvisualstudioをインストールしていないので入っておらず、再配布もされないファイルなので自分のやりたいことはできないということがわかりました。アドバイスいただきありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

リモートどうこうはとりあえずおいといて単純にデバッグすることを考えると

`Release` ビルドした EXE は `mfc140.dll` を参照している
`Debug` ビルドした EXE は `mfc140d.dll` を参照している
のは調査の通り。

一般ユーザーに配布してよい `vcredist.exe` では `mfc140.dll` はインストールされるけど `mfc140d.dll` はインストールされない、のも周知の事実。

そして EULA 的に `mfc140d.dll` は配布禁止になっている

ということで、普通に考えて「デバッグしたい環境に Visual Studio をインストールしてデバッグする」のが最短だと思われます（ライセンス問題がクリアであるとして）他の方法は遠回りすぎて時間の無駄っぽい。そうしたらリモートデバッグも不要で（仮想環境上で普通にデバッグすればよい）悩ましいことがなくなるはずです。

Comment: 774RRさん
回答いただきありがとうございます！そういうことなんですね。再配布されないということの意味もわかりました。素直にvisualstudioインストールするのがいいのですね。

Comment: 774RRさん
このホームページの手順で、仮想環境にmfc140d.dllをインストールすることができました。これで、visualstudioをインストールすることなく対応できました。ありがとうございました。
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/windows/walkthrough-deploying-a-visual-cpp-application-by-using-a-setup-project?view=vs-2019

Comment: それは仮想環境に `mfc140d.dll` を(再)配布していることになり EULA 違反っス、たぶん。